# Swift converting BLE characteristic value to a string

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am having an issue that is making no sense. Everything that I am doing I would think is pretty standard for BLE. Anyways, I have a BLE module that I am sending string data from to an iOS application and I am displaying this data on an interface. Since this is my first run using BLE code on an iOS application, I am using the tutorial from adafruit as a guide which can be found here: [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/crack-the-code/overview)

As I said, pretty standard stuff. Nothing special here. The code that I have written is able to perform all of the BLE steps. But, when it gets the data, the data is `/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0`. At first, I thought the source on the transmitting side was incorrect. But I opened another test app that lets me see sent BLE data and the data coming in is correctly formatted. It must be an issue with my code. I am not sure why this is happening or what the issue is. I could really use another pair of eyes to see if there is any issue with my code:

My code init code:

```
required init(parent: ViewController) {

        self.parent = parent

        self.bluetoothOn = false;

        bodyTemperature = 0
        airPressure = 0
        lightLevel = 0
        fanSpeed = 0
        Humidity = 0
        otherBatteryLevel = 0
        wifiStatus = "Good"

        super.init()

        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        //   self.periphal = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
```

My didupdateState code:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            if centralManager.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn{
                bluetoothOn = true
                self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [ATP_SERVICE_UUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : false])
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```

My didDiscover code:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        stopScan()
        self.blePeripheral = peripheral
        self.RSSI = RSSI
        self.blePeripheral.delegate = self
        centralManager?.connect(blePeripheral, options: nil)
        print("Found BLE module")
   //     blePeripheral.discoverServices([ATP_SERVICE_UUID])


    }
```

my didConnect code:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected to BLE device")
        centralManager?.stopScan()
        blePeripheral.delegate = self
        blePeripheral.discoverServices([ATP_SERVICE_UUID])
    }
```

My didDiscoverServices code:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else{
            return
        }

        for service in services{
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([ATP_UART_WRITE14_UUID, ATP_UART_READ13_UUID, ATP_NOTIFY_UUID], for: service)
        }

        print("Discovered Services: \(services)")
    }
```

My didDiscoverCharacteristics code:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else{
            return
        }

        print ("Found \(characteristics.count) characteristics")

        for characteristic in characteristics{
            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(ATP_UART_READ13_UUID){
                readCharacteristic = characteristic
              //  blePeripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: readCharacteristic!)
                blePeripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Rx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")

            }

            if(characteristic.uuid.isEqual(ATP_UART_WRITE14_UUID)){
                writeCharacteristic = characteristic
                print("Tx characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")

            }
        }
    }
```

My didupdateNotificationState code:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if(error != nil){
            print("Error changing notification state:\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

        } else {
            print("Characteristic's value subscribed")
        }

        if(characteristic.isNotifying){
            print("Subscribed. Notification has begun for: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }
```

And lastly, my didUpdateValueFor:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if characteristic == readCharacteristic{
       //     let ASCIIString = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            var stringFromData = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
            if stringFromData != "" {
                let textArray = stringFromData!.components(separatedBy: "\n\r")

                for line in textArray{
                    if line.hasPrefix("bodyTemperature:") {
                        var splitString = line.characters.split(separator: ":").map(String.init)
                        bodyTemperature = Float(splitString[1])!
                        self.delegate?.PQEData(didRecieveData: bodyTemperature)
                    } else if line.hasPrefix("enclosurePressure:") {
                        var splitString = line.characters.split(separator: ":").map(String.init)
                        airPressure = Float(splitString[1])!
                        self.delegate?.PQEData(didRecieveData: airPressure)
                    } else if line.hasPrefix("lightLevel:") {
                        var splitString = line.characters.split(separator: ":").map(String.init)
                        lightLevel = Float(splitString[1])!
                        self.delegate?.PQEData(didRecieveData: lightLevel)
                    } else if line.hasPrefix("humidity:") {
                        var splitString = line.characters.split(separator: ":").map(String.init)
                        Humidity = Float(splitString[1])!
                        self.delegate?.PQEData(didRecieveData: Humidity)
                    } else if line.hasPrefix("BATT:") {
                        var splitString = line.characters.split(separator: ":").map(String.init)
                        otherBatteryLevel = Float(splitString[1])!
                        self.delegate?.PQEData(didRecieveData: otherBatteryLevel)
                    } else if line.hasPrefix("fanSpeed:") {
                        var splitString = line.characters.split(separator: ":").map(String.init)
                        fanSpeed = Int(splitString[1])!
                        self.delegate?.PQEData(didRecieveData: fanSpeed)
                    } else if line.hasPrefix("wifiStatus:") {
                        var splitString = line.characters.split(separator: ":").map(String.init)
                        wifiStatus = splitString[1]
                        self.delegate?.PQEData(didRecieveData: wifiStatus)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Additional Notes:

1) In the didDiscoverCharaceristics function, I have commented out the call to `blePeripheral.setNotifyValue` function. That is because on the line for the call to `peripheral.discoverCharacteristics` call, I am already discovering for the NOTIFY characteristics. I have also tested with the setNotifyValue uncommented and the results are the same.

2) I have a local variable called blePeriphal that stores a reference to the periphal for the ble device. Same applies for writeCharacteristic and readCharacteristic

3) When the `blePeripheral.setNotifyValue` function was uncommented, the `didUpdateNotificationStateFor` function was executed. However, the `if(error != nil)` statement would be true and the error that I would get would be: `Error changing notification state:Optional("The request is not supported.")`. I am not sure if this is related. However, the `didUpdateValueFor` function would still get executed.

4) The code that is giving me the issue is found in the `didUpdateValueFor` function and the line is: `var stringFromData = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)`

5) Yes, I did try `var stringFromData = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` and `var stringFromData = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)` and the results were the same. `StringFromData` is all `/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0`

Update:

6) So after some testing, I have come across an issue that may be related. The `didUpdateValueFor` delegate is only being called once and after that, never again. I have verified this by constantly sending a string once every 1/4 second.

Comment: `didUpdate` is only being called once because you are only reading once. You do need to use notification for your read characteristic because you need to get the new value when the peripheral changes it (sends data). You are probably getting the 0 data because you are reading before the peripheral has ever sent anything to you. The fact that you got an error when you tried to enable notifications suggests that you tried to enable notifications in the wrong characteristic. Perhaps you have the read and write characteristic identifiers swapped around?

Comment: Hey Paulw, Thank you for your response. I apologize for the delay but I was backed up. Sure, I will try your suggestion.